# Add action to woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I have a plugin which has one `php` file that contains this code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: shareIno
....
*/

include ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php';


function saveRecentProducts(){
    file_put_contents("flog.txt","TesT",FILE_NO_DEFAULT_CONTEXT);
}
add_action("woocommerce_api_create_product",'saveRecentProducts');
add_action("woocommerce_duplicate_product",'saveRecentProducts');
add_action('transition_post_status', 'saveRecentProducts', 10);`
```

This action is never called... If someone knows how to fix it tell me please...

Comment: Do you need all three action to call the same function ? or any one of theme ?

Comment: if i just add  `transition_post_status` i can handle all of that ....but its not work

Comment: have you tried to change post status with `transition_post_status` ? is it working as it should, if it is working you should progress, if not first need to find out why changing status not working with `transition_post_status` as this is used for that purpose.

Comment: `transition_post_status` look in woocommerce docs to see when is this hook fired. thats most likely reason your function is never being called

Comment: there's a plugin called Query Monitor,  install that plugin, visit the page where your hook suppose to be fired, check the hooks section if its there

Comment: do die("I am in"); in saveRecentProducts and check is function is getting called or not maybe file_put_contents is throwing some error

Comment: tnx @WisdmLabs thats right